# What brand is this door latch bolt?

Tags: doors

I am trying to find out what the brand of this drive-in locking door latch is. It is circa 1975. I am planning to replace four of them.

[image]

Comment: If it's circa 1975.. would it not be easier to buy an adjustable latch?

Answer (score 0):

That is a classic style mobile home latch. It's probably a generic model. You can still get an exact replacement from many sources. There is probably a local mobile home supply near you that deals with Blevins.

Comment: Apart from the lack of a faceplate, it looks just like a normal door latch.  Eg https://www.amazon.com/Schlage-Replacement-Deadlatch-Faceplate-Polished/dp/B003F38Z7E.